# How can I grep a directory based on the contents of two successive lines?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How can I grep a **directory** for lines that contain "Foo", but **only** get matches when the next line also contains "Bar"?

Comment: The problem is now totally different than the original :/ Maybe better to revert the old versions & POST another one ? Moreover the new question is not clear for me.

Comment: @sputnick - how so? I specified a directory when I first posted the question; I only bolded it because people weren't noticing.

Comment: Nevermind, that will works, I will edit my POST accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

@warl0ck pointed me in the right direction with `pcregrep`, but I said "contains", not "is", and I asked about a directory, not a file.

This seems to work for me.

```
pcregrep -rMi 'Foo(.*)\n(.*)Bar' .
```

Answer (score 6):

Grep itself doesn't seem to support it, use pcregrep instead:

```
Foo
Bar
Foo
abc
```

`pcregrep -M "Foo\nBar" file`

Got:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Comment: The OP didn't say that `Foo` and `Bar` would comprise the entire line.

Answer (score 6):

With a `sed` script :

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

/^Foo/{
    h         # put the matching line in the hold buffer
    n         # going to nextline
    /^Bar/{   # matching pattern in newline
        H     # add the line to the hold buffer
        x     # return the entire paragraph into the pattern space
        p     # print the pattern space
        q     # quit the script now
    }
}
```

To use it :

```
chmod +x script.sed
printf '%s\n' * | ./script.sed
```

The `printf` here display all files in the current directory on one line each, and pass it to `sed`.

**Note** : this is sorted by alphabetical order.

More infos of useful `pattern space` and `hold space` [HERE](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-56).

*grymoire.com* have really good stuff about `shell` programming.

Comment: What does `h, n, H, x, p, q` means? Very interesting.

Comment: See my comments. More infos on `pattern space` & `hold space` : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-56 or in french http://www.commentcamarche.net/faq/9536-sed-introduction-a-sed-part-i

Comment: POST adapted to work on a directory

Answer (score 4):

Using `grep` only, you could construct the following pipe:

`grep -A1 'Foo' input_file | grep -B1 'Bar' | grep 'Foo'`

The first `grep` will get all the lines that contain `Foo` as well as the line after the match. Then we get lines that contain `Bar` as well as the line before the match, and finally extract the lines from this output that contain `Foo`.

**EDIT:** As [manatwork](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10412/manatwork) pointed out, there are some problematic cases to be observant of. Although an interesting challenge, due to `grep`'s line oriented functionality, any solution with it is likely to be a 'hack' and you are probably better off using something like `pcregrep` which is more suited to the task at hand.

Comment: Nice. I asked about a directory though; this seems to work: `find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep -A1 'Foo' | grep -B1 'Bar'`

Comment: That will also list occurrences with both “Foo” and “Bar” on the same line.

Comment: @manatwork: Lines that contain "Foo" and "Bar" are "lines that contain 'Foo'" which is was what was asked.

Comment: @tojrobinson, what about the “but **only** get matches when the next line also contains "Bar"” part? http://pastebin.com/Yj8aeCEA

Answer (score 3):

While I prefer Nathan's solution using `pcregrep`, here is solution using only grep

```
grep -o -z -P  'Foo(.*)\n(.*)Bar' file
```

Options explanation:

- `-o` print only matched part. Necessary since inclusion of `-z` will printout the whole file (unless there is a \0 somewhere)
- `-z` Treat the input as a set of lines, each  terminated  by  a  zero
            byte  (the  ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.
- `-P` perl regex syntax

EDIT : This version prints out entire matched lines

```
    grep -o -P -z  '(.*)Foo(.*)\n(.*)Bar(.*)' file
```

Comment: Cool trick what `-z`. Some “(.*)” before and after the whole expression would make it output the entire matched lines. For now substrings before “Foo” and after “Bar” are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '/bar/ && prev != "" {print FILENAME ": " prev "\n" FILENAME ": " $0}
     /foo/ {prev=$0; next}
     {prev=""}' file1...
```

(general note about awk limitation: beware that if some file names may contain "=" characters, you'll need to pass them as `./filename` instead of `filename` to awk)